# Is it worth stashing items for twinks?

Tags: diablo-iii

While playing with my main char I sometimes find some quite good items for my other chars but at higher levels, so I cannot use them immediately.

Is it worth stashing them or should I just sell them in the AH and buy similar items once my twinks reach that level? I mean they should cost about the same amount of gold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save all decent rare rings & amulets; they are hard to come across compared to other equipment. Also, if you are playing DH & will later go for Monk (or vice versa) - save your lower level DEX items as hand-me-downs if they are good.

You need to elaborate what is meant by 'quite good items' - I was trying to save all semi-decent rares, but its impractical and you want to focus on specific properties like

- Gives boost to main stat
- Has other useful props besides MF or GF (if ur focused on that)
- For weapons, has life leech or 'on hit'

**Saving space in your stash**

- Even if you don't plan to play a particular class, might work better to start a lvl 1 char so he/she holds the class specific items which are taking up a lot of space
- Don't stock up much for the first 10-15 levels as they pass by *very* quickly: move any 'starter' equip onto new chars, but feel free to just keep a decent weapon and sell everything else
- Remember that you can also park some good sword/shield, 2h weapons etc. on the followers. If you plan to actually use the follower, give them stuff that boosts stats but otherwise it is extra slots for amulet/rings etc.

Answer (score 3):

Its quite likely that we're going to see some significant inflation in the game over time.  Since more gold is constantly being generated, people will be willing to pay more for what they want, and thus prices will go up.  So unless you need the money now, I would say that you should **hold on to it**, using additional characters as excess "stash" as needed.

If inflation occurs and you end up wanting the item (or its equivalent), you'll have to pay more in the future to get it back.  If inflation occurs and you don't end up wanting the item, you'll get more money by selling it in the future then by selling it now.  So the only reason to sell it now is if the item is unlikely to ever be auctionable (because it just isn't something people will want), or you don't have the space to hold onto it (with 10 character slots, it should take quite a while to reach this point), or you need the money immediately for some big purchase.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, I'd suggest selling your items and buying better suited ones when you play a particular character.  It's really kind of hard to determine if at the time you'd be able to use a particular bit of gear, if it would be appropriate to your build.

More often than not, if I stash a bit of gear I can't currently use on any of my characters, I end up coming back to it later and going "why did I save this?  This is junk."  Or I'll stash a halfway decent rare for a particular slot, and then get to the point I would use it, and I've found *just one good piece of gear, and it's for that slot.*  (sigh)

If something has a very high primary stat for the item level, or if I find a legendary, sometimes I'll hang on to it.  Most stuff, though, goes straight to the vendor.  Interesting/exceptional rares end up at the auction house.

Instead of stashing random loot for twinking, I keep a few items on hand that I bought at the AH:

- A good socketed helm, for a +XP% Ruby (must be level 15 or higher)
- A good universal socketed weapon or two (several classes can use 1-handed swords, for instance) with a +DPS ruby
- Perhaps a couple of bits of +primary stat gear with low level requirements, just to make the early going faster.

Comment: Plus with the staggering rate of deflation if you sell the item now and buy it back later, you would probably net profit.

Comment: @Nick You don't think that deflation is going to continue forever do you?  I think we're going to switch to inflation.  In fact, I think we're probably already experiencing inflation as many people are now past the initial level up period.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely save it if its an exceptional item, although if its only mediocre then I'll AH and buy better items later on.

The AH does not guarantee the availability of any item, so if you want something for later, save it.

Typically I keep all items stored for one specific character in one place (such as all my Wizard items in a specific row in my stash), and I'll periodically clean it out and sell duplicate items.