# How do I decide what items to save for future use

Tags: diablo-iii

How do people decide on which drops to save among the steady flood of items? Stash space is limited, and my earlier strategy of saving all rares and items with good MF stats isn't feasible any more.

I'm looking for answers on how to decide on what items to retain for

- Alts of any class that are lower level and could use this equipment in future
- Alternate gear for situational use - boss killing vs AoE mobs? Specific troublesome elites (molten fire chains with melee) in higher difficulties?
- Adding in MF or GF gear for occasional item hunting runs
- Even good items for the *same character at a lower level* (to give away to friends, and yes I'm not confident of always recognizing these just because I have leveled a particular class)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it worth stashing items for twinks?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69920/is-it-worth-stashing-items-for-twinks)

Comment: @bwarner: I actually remembered to ask this after seeing that question, this is more 'I am a packrat anyway, but what do I throw out & keep?' (also its not just for alts).

Comment: Isn't it the same question?

Comment: Btw, those voting it down - I'd like any suggestions to improve the question; my stash is getting crowded and I don't want to throw out the wrong items (ie. answers would be useful to me, I don't care about the contest & not asking just for some points)

Comment: Saving for main doesn't really make sense, either its better than what you have now and you use it immediately, or its not and you'll never use it.  Alternate gear sets for your main is kind of a niche case, and isn't even mentioned in your answer.  So your question ends up being about saving for alts too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3554/discussion-between-alok-and-bwarner)

Comment: Cleaned up some comments. I'd like any input on improving this question for those who think its not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my current, evolving strategy of what to keep & throw:

**Things to not save**

- Most equipment below around level 15 or so; excluding good weapons & amulet/rings: you level too fast to care about it.
- Items with good stat bonuses split between different main stats: e.g. armor with STR & DEX, without other good mods I pass it up since neither barb or DH/Monk will get full use out of it.
- Amulets & rings with a single good stat (ooh look, 8% MF! but nothing else ...)
- Blue armor just because it has 2 sockets

**Things to save**

- Weapons with high dps, life steal/life on hit usable by most classes: better with sockets and any other useful properties.
- Amulets or rings with a lot of +stats: quick boost to alt's followers
- Amulets/rings with bonus to a single main stat; and maybe VIT, life regen etc.
- I like to have atleast some items in various level ranges with life regen

Comment: This is sort of subjective; it really only applies to you.  What if you had a wizard, or focused on other items?

Comment: @fbueckert: If I had a good list, wouldn't be asking the question ;) I am only starting off with my own opinions (which ofc. are subjective!) and hoping for the input of some experts to improve :)

Comment: According to the FAQ, you shouldn't be asking questions such as 'Every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”.  This question is far too subjective.

Comment: Disagree that all answers are equally valid here; do you mean there is no constructive advice on picking the items to save? You can always specify the class in your answer, doesn't have to be generic to everyone.