# Automatically vendor certain items?

Tags: diablo-iii

I still seem to have a lot of problems deciding on what exactly is a good piece of rare equipment to keep in order to sell on the AH & what should I just automatically vendor/salvage within the game, & thus I have three almost full tabs on my stash & nine almost completely full mule characters--& I'm still accumulating more junk. :-0

For weapons, I've started automatically getting rid of anything one-handed with DPS below 500 (regardless of stats), and ditto for anything two-handed with DPS below 1000 (again, almost regardless of stats).  For shields, anything with a block percentage below 16% gets sold off immediately.  However, it's stuff like helms, chest pieces, gloves, boots, amulets, shoulders, rings, etc. that I can almost never decide whether it's worthwhile to keep or not.

Does anyone have some good criteria for just getting rid of other items based on (for e.g.) armor value, or ilvl, or something else?  Looking for a quick & easy way to just go through & thin out my stashes & mules characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: eh. I doubt you've vendored this, but certain items below 500 dps can still sell for a few million.  Namely, daggers with high LoH, high base critical damage, and a socket (stats optional but make them even more valuable).

Comment: Always try to keep trifecta items or items that have 2 out of 3 trifecta stats i.e Crit chance, crit damage and attack speed. But everyone should know this

Answer (score 7):

By and large most items you pick up are going to be junk, but whether you should keep or sell them comes down to a few simple criteria, in my experience.

- Would I use this item if I had the appropriate character?  If no, vendor.
- As noted in comments, is some combination of stats overwhelmingly good, but it's lacking some modifiers?  For example, does it have +CritChance +CritDam and +IAS?  Does it have an absurd amount of +LOH that might make it useful?  Does it have slot max +MF% or +GF%?  Huge dps?  In other words, is there someone who might want the item even though it has no (ie)strength or vitality?
- Is it a hard to fill spot?  Right now good chest armor is expensive, at least in part because a lot of people are crafting 6 property armor which is a 100k gamble.  Rings and amulets don't drop as often as anyone would like.  Or is it the 30th pair of boots with no movement % you've seen today?  The 40th set of shoulders without +resAll?

If you've decided to vendor a rare, then one thing I suggest you also consider is salvaging it, if it will produce inferno quality crafting materials and it's sell value is less than the auction house price for those materials (right now that's about 1,000 gold)  Though you won't immediately gain from this, it will make crafting more attractive to you later on if you don't outright sell your materials for profit.

As a personal guideline I do the following:

- Automatically drop any white or grey items I picked up.
- Almost entirely automatically vendor every blue I see (except for an amazing item as noted above)
- Almost entirely automatically vendor every yellow I see below level 62 unless it has a redeeming combination of properties, especially  and good +resAll
- Sort my inventory by item type then by dps/armor ... when I have more than 2 rows of 1 type start getting rid of any of the lower end items.  This has gradually come to mean 800 dps on 2h and 700 dps on 1h in the absence of a good reason, everything without resAll or 19/20% mf, and so on.
- Check auction house for every orange and green before salvaging.

***TL;DR*** Turn your approach around.  Assume everything is getting vendored/salvaged unless it makes a good case for staying.

Answer (score 0):

Related post: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69925/25150

There are some general properties that make items valuable or atleast let you sell them above vendor price. Some stats to look out for:

- All Resistance in higher amounts (around 50+ in most slots)
- Main stat/Vit (Dex/Vit for monk or DH, Str/Vit for barbs). For melee chars esp., armor without high AR or VIT is usually bad unless it has an absolutely amazing set of other stats (very unlikely) and they can get the required tankiness elsewhere.
- Magic Find
- Life on Hit
- Class specific items < general ones; unless they have high values of their unique properties (Arcane on crit for Wizards, Discipline for DH etc.)
- Equipment for level 60s is generally more valuable, as most people don't spend a lot for gear they will outlevel soon (i.e. an iLvl 30 armor better be really awesome for you to even consider keeping it)

> it's stuff like helms, chest pieces, gloves, boots, amulets, shoulders, rings, etc. that I can almost never decide whether it's worthwhile to keep or not.

Some criteria I consider for these slots:

- Helm: Socket (for ruby or topaz etc.)
- Chest armor: 3 sockets + good stats
- Gloves: IAS, CritChance or CritDmg (if you have good rolls on 2 or all 3,it will be worth a fortune esp. if there is also a main stat)
- Boots: Movement Speed (12% only, unless other stats are great in which case I keep them around even for 9+% MS)
- Amulets & rings: *Be extra careful before vendoring or salvaging them*

  - Cannot be crafted and are rarer drops, also they are useful to followers as well
  - High +VIT on ammy/ring, even without other good stats, may be useful to equip on a follower
  - You can put situational rings on current follower for storage & easy access. e.g. a high LoH amulet that lowers dps but is useful vs reflect mobs.

---

Now, what if you don't want to keep track of all these details and want simpler criteria to deal with your packrat hoard?

- Would you use this on your char/alt if you had that class? Or assuming a friend with mediocre gear, would this be an upgrade for him?
- Does it sell for atleast 3x the vendor value on AH? If so, then just consistently sell them with Buyout at 2.5x sell cost, and clear out inventory at a small profit.